# How to add a trailing slash to this one particular url in apache using a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2

When a user types in www.example.co.uk/beta, I want the traffic to be sent to www.example.co.uk/beta/. But only for that url ie, when the url ends /beta.

How do I accomplish this in apache?

I have tried:

```
<Location /beta>
    DirectorySlash Off
    ProxyPass  http://testserver.co.uk
    ProxyPassReverse http://testserver.co.uk
</Location>
```

With no success

Please note the proxypass directives are for my reverse proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple rewrite rule to deal with the traling slash; straight from the [apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/beta$  /beta/  [R]
```

Comment: Thanks. What I was mistakenly failing to realise was the location directive picks up both /beta and /beta/ and /beta/whatever etc. Adding that regex condition of $ at the end forces it to match only /beta and not /beta/ etc. Of course I put that rewrite rule inside the location

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it you might want to do it this way:

```
<Proxy /beta>
   ProxyPass http://testserver.co.uk/beat/
   ProxyPassReverse http://testserver.co.uk/beta/ 
</Proxy>
```

This will work also:

```
ProxyPass  /beta http://testserver.co.uk/beat/
ProxyPassReverse /beta http://testserver.co.uk/beta/
```

You could also use ProxyPassMatch:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(/beta)$ http://testserver.co.uk/$1/
ProxyPassReverse $1 http://testserver.co.uk/$1/
```

You can find out more [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch).